# Xamarin with teamcity giving refernce error

Tags: c#, android, reference, xamarin, teamcity

I am trying to setup teamcity for the android project but while building I am facing this error

```
Agent\DAgent.cs(8, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RestSharp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
Agent\DAgent.cs(9, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
Agent\DCAgent.cs(3, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
Agent\DCgent.cs(4, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RestSharp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
BootStrapper.cs(6, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RestSharp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
Controllers\DController.cs(11, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RestSharp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
Controllers\LController.cs(8, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

and such other errors, now i am confused since in xamarin studio in my system the project builds fine, RestSharp i have added as a component as well as in the reference (RestSharp.Monodroid)
can some one help on this

Comment: Are you actually including the Component in your repo?  The build system can download Nuget packages automatically, but not Components.

Comment: @Jason yes there is a component folder in my repo with restsharp and json.net

Comment: And what about nuget packages? Do you push the into your remote repo as well?